# Индексация массивов C#

Tags: c#, массивы, индексация

Добрый день,
Возникла такая проблема:
Элементы в массивах в C# индексируются с нуля: 0, 1, 2...
Мне нужно каждому присвоить свой индекс:

```
int[] array;    
//Какая-то магия    
array[-1] = 0;    
array[0] = 0; //и т. д.
```

Это вообще возможно? Если да, то как?

Comment: @Владилав, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Скорее всего, вам нужно что-то другое. Опишите, чего вы хотите добиться по смыслу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению с обычными массивами такое сделать не получится.
Зато можно воспользоваться коллекцией **Dictionary**. Например так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Создаем коллекцию Dictionary с ключом типа int и значением типа int 
        var values = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        // Добавляем значения по любому ключу, в том числе и отрицательному
        values.Add(-5, 1);
        values.Add(-2, 2);
        values.Add(4, 3);

        // Выведет: 1 2 3
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", values[-5], values[-2], values[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, это возможно.

Comment: Так как же это возможно?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то ваша проблема заключается в использовании отрицательных индексов массивов. Что ж, если это так, то я предложу вам свой вариант, заключающийся в создании простой обертки( Wrapper ) над коллекцией данных `Dictionary<T,T>` . Класс-обертка:

```
public class MyArray {

        private Dictionary<int, int> Data = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        public MyArray() { }
        // "Фундамент" нашего Wrapper`а
        public int this [int index]{

            set { Data.Add(index, value); }
            get { return Data[index]; }

        }

    }
```

**Использование:**

```
...
MyArray my = new MyArray();
my[-1] = -1;
my[0] = 0;

MessageBox.Show(my[-1].ToString());  // "-1"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать класс с индексатором и использовать его как тип данных для массива, если необходимо индексировать не с 0.

```
/* Create a specifiable range array class. 
   The RangeArray class allows indexing to begin at 
   some value other than zero. When you create a RangeArray, 
   you specify the beginning and ending index. Negative 
   indexes are also  allowed.  For example, you can create 
   arrays that index from -5 to 5, 1 to 10, or 50 to 56. 
*/

using System;

class RangeArray
{
    // Private data. 
    int[] a; // reference to underlying array   
    int lowerBound; // smallest index 
    int upperBound; // largest index

    // An auto-implemented, read-only Length property. 
    public int Length { get; private set; }

    // An auto-implemented, read-only Error property. 
    public bool Error { get; private set; }

    // Construct array given its size.  
    public RangeArray(int low, int high)
    {
        high++;
        if (high <= low)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Indices");
            high = 1; // create a minimal array for safety 
            low = 0;
        }
        a = new int[high - low];
        Length = high - low;

        lowerBound = low;
        upperBound = --high;
    }

    // This is the indexer for RangeArray.  
    public int this[int index]
    {
        // This is the get accessor.  
        get
        {
            if (ok(index))
            {
                Error = false;
                return a[index - lowerBound];
            }
            else
            {
                Error = true;
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // This is the set accessor.  
        set
        {
            if (ok(index))
            {
                a[index - lowerBound] = value;
                Error = false;
            }
            else Error = true;
        }
    }

    // Return true if index is within bounds.  
    private bool ok(int index)
    {
        if (index >= lowerBound & index <= upperBound) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

// Demonstrate the index-range array.  
class RangeArrayDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        RangeArray ra = new RangeArray(-5, 5);
        RangeArray ra2 = new RangeArray(1, 10);
        RangeArray ra3 = new RangeArray(-20, -12);

        // Demonstrate ra. 
        Console.WriteLine("Length of ra: " + ra.Length);

        for (int i = -5; i <= 5; i++)
            ra[i] = i;

        Console.Write("Contents of ra: ");
        for (int i = -5; i <= 5; i++)
            Console.Write(ra[i] + " ");

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        // Demonstrate ra2. 
        Console.WriteLine("Length of ra2: " + ra2.Length);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            ra2[i] = i;

        Console.Write("Contents of ra2: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            Console.Write(ra2[i] + " ");

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        // Demonstrate ra3. 
        Console.WriteLine("Length of ra3: " + ra3.Length);

        for (int i = -20; i <= -12; i++)
            ra3[i] = i;

        Console.Write("Contents of ra3: ");
        for (int i = -20; i <= -12; i++)
            Console.Write(ra3[i] + " ");

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Индексатор, который возвращает ошибку путём установки поля? Вы не ошиблись тысячелетием? Подумайте, что будет в случае

    var ra = RangeArray(0, 1);
    if (ra[-100] == 0 || ra[0] == 0)
    {
        ...

(не говоря уже об одновременном доступе на чтение из нескольких потоков).

Answer (score 0):

Массив нужно кроме объявления, ещё и проинициализировать:

```
int[] array = new int[numberOfElements];
```

---

А сделать объект с индексом `−1` у Вас не получится: [Массивы на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) (см. Общие сведения о массивах, п. 4)

Comment: Я это прекрасно знаю, Вы можете ответить на мой вопрос?
Ведь его нужно как-то по-особому инициализировать, индексируя с -1

Comment: Исправил ответ.